# HTML CSS Align Text In Center of Rectangle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align this content word in middle of rectangle. Word 'test' is on the top. I used everything,   text-align:center; vertical-align:middle,
  justify-content:center, align-items: center, and still not working

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(77,77,77);
  border-radius:7px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"> 
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it. You're using the properties `justify-content` and `align-items`, but not the `flex` display that these properties require to work. Furthermore, I removed `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle`, as they are no longer needed.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(77,77,77);
  border-radius:7px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"> 
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add display: flex or display:grid :)

```css
.rectangle {
      height: 75px;
      width: 75px;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
      border-radius: 7px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
    Test
  </div>
```